# ToIntArray - Replacement function

Tags: c#, datatable, mono, xamarin.android, accord.net

According to http://crsouza.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/decision-trees-in-c.html I use

```
DataTable symbols = codebook.Apply(data); 
int[][] inputs  = symbols.ToIntArray("Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind"); 
int[]   outputs = symbols.ToIntArray("PlayTennis").GetColumn(0);
```

But in .net 4.0 and in mono there is no `ToIntArray`, also I could not find any replacement function for it.

How does `ToIntArray` convert `symbols` or, what does `ToIntArray` look like?

Comment: I will remove my answer as it was wrong, I think you should add your own answer telling us how you solved this in case someone else has the same problem. Greetings from Sweden (I Live in Sydney though..)!

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you have to import the Accord.Math namespace first. If your compiler/environment still doesn't support extension methods, you could also try calling Matrix.ToArray<int>(...) explicitly

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to download and add the [Accord framework](http://accord-framework.net/) to your project (Note: there is a chance it might have dependencies which are not supported by Xamarin's .NET implementation), then luckily it's open source, so if you want to just see the code it's available to the public.

To answer the specific question, the `.ToIntArray` extension method (which is just an "alias" method for `ToArray<int>()`) can be seen here:

https://code.google.com/p/accord/source/browse/trunk/Sources/Accord.Math/Matrix/Matrix.Conversions.cs

However, the `.Apply` and `.GetColumn` methods (from your sample code) is also part of the framework, so you'd probably need to look at that code as well.  See Matrix.Common and Matrix.Selection.

Answer (score 0):

As of the current version, you can use [ToInt32()](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/Overload_Accord_Math_Matrix_ToInt32.htm), as well as ToDouble(), ToSingle(), ToBoolean() and others to perform type conversions of arrays.